# Why is the order of an algorithm generally more important than the speed of the processor?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, big-o, complexity-theory

So, I know that the efficiency is determined by the algorithms and data structures
used in a solution. But, I don't really get how the order of an algorithm more important than the speed of the processor?

Comment: I believe order refers to [Big O](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation), in which case the reason a (Big O) order is more important to performance is simply executing the algorithm uses less steps.

Comment: It's not.  I run algorithms with an exponential worst-case on reasonably-large inputs with regularity.

Comment: I think the strongest statement that can be made is that for sufficiently large *n*, the order of an algorithm is more important for performance than the speed of the processor. However, in many real-life scenarios, *n* is not large enough for the lower-order algorithm to be actually faster, and there are other practical considerations, such as the simplicity and maintainability of the code implementing the algorithm. This question therefore has no clear answer and will invite opinions and discussion.

Comment: +1 for tmyklebu & njuffa. My opinion (plagiarized from other comments) is that both "Cpu" and "Complexity" are important. (A) cpu is important in initial stages, where it is decided that (for example) HP laptop will not be used but IBM supercomputer will be used (B) Once cpu is decided, now the algorithm is selected. Now O(n) may be selected over O(n^2), but it does not mean "Complexity" is more important than "Cpu" generally.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

A typical personal computer can do `10^8 calculations per second`. 

And the world's fastest supercomputer does `10^16 calculations per second`.

So suppose you had an O(n) algorithm running on your laptop/desktop right now. And an O(n^2) algorithm running on the world's fastest supercomputer simultaneously. And if n = 10^10,

Running time on the PC = 10^10 / 10^8 = `100 seconds`.  
Running time on the supercomputer = 10^20 / 10^16 = `10000 seconds`.

Thus clearly the laptop outperforms the supercomputer by a huge margin. And is infact 100 times faster while employing just a better algorithm.

Another reason we look for better algorithms is because of the **[scalability](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scalability)** problem. According to [moore's law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moore%27s_law), **computing power doubles every 18 months**. So even if a supercomputer can handle huge inputs really fast today, it may not be able to do so some time later when the problem size has increased manyfold while the computing power would have only doubled in the next 18 months.

Comment: The clock speed you gave for the supercomputer of course assumes that the algorithm can fully take advantage of the parallel architecture.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen  
Yes, I know that. Just thinking about the worst case bounds to convince the OP about the benefits of a better algorithm.

Comment: This answer assumes that O(n^2) means n^2.  0.1 n^2 and 1000 n^2 + 10^100 are both O(n^2). I'm surprised that you bring up Moore's law as some sort of indication that computing power increases slowly with time. Normally Moore's law is cited for the opposite reason.

Comment: @DouglasZare The point here is that a better algorithm is preferable any day. To emphasize this, I have talked about the performance considerations in the current scenario and some years later when the processor speed increases. So that's why I have mentioned Moore's law. Because even if the algo is great today, it may not be so tomorrow. And don't you think you are being too pedantic in the analysis by considering the constant factors. I think the point emphasized in the answer is clear and the OP understands it very well.

Comment: @downvoters. Mind explaining the downvote?

Comment: You quote Moores law incorrectly. Moore's law does not state that computing power doubles every 18 month, it is the transistor count. This is an important difference, as performance does not scale with transistor count.

Comment: Nikunj Banka, you have several things wrong starting with the number of calculations per second a typical personal computer can do. Why not fix them? Even if the OP is satisfied by a highly flawed answer, you should not be. And no, I don't think it is too pedantic to be correct about what O(n^2) means instead of building on common misunderstandings like the conceptual error of thinking that O(n^2) means n^2 or cn^2. I don't think it helps to use an incorrect version of Moore's law backwards.

Comment: Why would anybody run O(n^2) algorithm on the super computer, when there is some O(n) algorithm available ? My opinion is (A) cpu is important in initial stages, where it is decided that (for example) laptop will not be used but the supercomputer will be used (B) Once cpu is decided, now the algorithm is selected. Now O(n) will be selected over O(n^2), but it does not mean Complexity is more important than cpu.

Answer (score 5):

Let's look at an example:

You have an algorithm with an order of O(n^3). You're running that algorithm on a processor that can handle n = 10 in 100 milliseconds.

If n goes to 10000, that processor would need 1158 days.

Getting a processor twice as fast would only cut that down to 579 days.

Even if you were able to get a processor ten times as fast, it would still take months.

But replacing that algorithm with one of order of O(n^2) and running that on the original processor would cut the time needed down to 2.8 hours.

Answer (score 2):

one cannot say order of an algorithm is more/less important than CPU speed!!! they are not comparable!!!!
we use orders to compare different algorithms with each other because we don't know the target architecture that algorithm will run. as another note the execution time of a program is depend on many factors such as cach miss rate, main memory hit ration and .... so in each execution program execution time may be differ with previous ones. as a result **we cannot compare two programs even by executing them on an structure!!!**

Answer (score 1):

Whether it is more important depends on the situation. The complexity order of an algorithm is not directly linked to its speed, there may be "worse" algorithms that solve a specific problem instance faster than a "better" algorithm. As explained by the other answers, the complexity order comes down to the question "*How does memory/time consumption grow with input size?*". For small inputs, you don't care. For average inputs, you benchmark your algorithms, and see which one runs faster on your hardware. The problem are **unexpectedly large inputs**: Now you care whether tenfold data means tenfold crunching time, hundredfold waiting time, or never-ending computation till the heat death of the universe.

A prominent example of this is the [Windows XP update mechanism](http://arstechnica.com/information-technology/2013/12/exponential-algorithm-making-windows-xp-miserable-could-be-fixed/). They are processing the list of installed updates using an algorithm with exponential running time. This was no issue and ran acceptably fast, until - decades later - the number of updates made this a real problem.

But as a computer scientist, I've got another view to share on what is more important: **Algorithmic complexity is much more interesting**. Figuring out an algorithm with better complexity is an intellectual problem. If you only cared for faster results, you can just as easily upgrade your hardware. You can get processing power for money. The speed of processors is more or less still improving - just get them and you trivially sped up your program<sup>[1]</sup>. Until you hit the edge (of technology or budget), and you need a better algorithm. Then you've got a though nut to crack. A brain teaser. Which is pure fun!

<sub>1: I'm not saying that making processors fast is trivial. But using them to solve problems is :-)</sub>

Answer (score 0):

Il try  to explain in a easy way.
The processor speed is measured in terms of cycles/sec and will vary from processor to processor. To judge a algo, we need a metric independent of this and based purely on the algo.
Let us say that a single operation in a algorithm requires one processor cycle.
So, for order of algo n, if input is of size n, n processor cycles are required.
If order is algo n^2, if input size is n, n^2 processor cycles are required. 
So you see, the order of a algorithm is a metric independent of the processor speed. The lower the order, faster it works. 

This is a very general answer but i hope it clears your doubt.